# Add custom view controller as root view controller in my mac application?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I already checked most of the answers to this question but mostly are for Cocoa Touch. I need to implement this in my appdelegate for mac application.

Once user is logged-in he will be redirected to the main screen else go to login screen.

```
let controller:NSWindowController = NSWindowController()
let viewController:NSViewController

let storyboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let stringLoginStatus = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(Constants.Key_LoginStatus) as? String
    if stringLoginStatus != nil
    {
        if stringLoginStatus == "true"
        {
            viewController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("Channel") as! NSViewController
        }
        else{
            viewController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! NSViewController
        }
    }
    else{
        viewController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! NSViewController
    }

    controller.window?.contentViewController = viewController
    controller.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

It shows and error as controller is not being initialized.

Comment: I don't even know what 'controller' and 'viewController' are.

Comment: I edit the code please Check @ElTomato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code to change your view controller:-

```
UIApplication.appWindow.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "customViewControl")
```

//MARK: Make UIApplication extension to get appWindow

```
    extension UIApplication {
        class var appWindow: UIWindow! {
            return (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!)!
        }
    }
```

//MARK: Make Storyboard extension to get main screen

```
extension UIStoryboard {
    class var main: UIStoryboard {
        let storyboardName: String = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "UIMainStoryboardFile") as! String
        return UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    }
```

}

Comment: UIApplication is for Cocoa Touch or iPhone,iPad application. I need for Cocoa, mac application( NSApplication not UIApplication).